# Discrepancy between values in htop and /proc/meminfo

Tags: linux, memory, proc, htop

From the author of htops answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41224738/how-to-calculate-system-memory-usage-from-proc-meminfo-like-htop/41251290#41251290

I got to know that the total memory in htop is calculated from /proc/meminfo. I think I could crosscheck this in code as well and it checks out.
However compared to memory bar in htop. I see a major difference in the memory values shown in /proc/meminfo.

In my /proc/meminfo the memory consumption reads

```
MemTotal:       4144807288 kB
MemFree:        3513532764 kB
MemAvailable:   3936769368 kB
Buffers:         1119392 kB
```

So the Total used memory , which I think represented by the memory bar should be MemTotal-MemFree in GBs which should be (4144807288-3513532764)/1024^2=602Gb as far as I understand.
However for me this value shows almost 180Gb. Could anyone explain how the values in /proc/meminfo and one in htop would become different.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess why the values differ is the following:

htop "180G" value does not include system buffers and other memory used by operating system, while /proc/meminfo reports it as allocated

Digging into https://github.com/htop-dev/htop/blob/541c17c975bc8a4f1f243e568006b0e26ae52c47/linux/LinuxMachine.c#L130 can help to understand how htop values are calculated